# Finding the total area and cover area of multiple polygon

Tags: c++, slice, polygon, computational-geometry

I'm trying to solve this problem using the slicing technic.

But I just passed the first two test cases in this gym (Problem A)

[2017-2018 ACM-ICPC East Central North America Regional Contest (ECNA 2017)](https://codeforces.com/gym/101673)

The whole step in my code looks like this:

1. calculate the total area using vector cross when inputting the polygon information.
2. find all the endpoints and intersection points, and record x value of them.
3. for each slice (sort x list and for each interval) find the lines from every polygon which crosses this interval and store this smaller segment.
4. sort segments.
5. for each trapezoid or triangle, calculate the area if this area is covered by some polygon.
6. sum them all to find the cover area.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

using ll = long long;
template<typename T> using p = pair<T, T>;
template<typename T> using vec = vector<T>;
template<typename T> using deq = deque<T>;

// #define dbg

#define yccc ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false), cin.tie(0)
#define al(a) a.begin(),a.end()
#define F first
#define S second
#define eb emplace_back

const int INF = 0x3f3f3f3f;
const ll llINF = 1e18;
const int MOD = 1e9+7;
const double eps = 1e-9;
const double PI = acos(-1);

double fcmp(double a, double b = 0, double eps = 1e-9) {
    if (fabs(a-b) < eps) return 0;
    return a - b;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
istream& operator>>(istream& in, pair<T1, T2>& a) { in >> a.F >> a.S; return in; }

template<typename T1, typename T2>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, pair<T1, T2> a) { out << a.F << ' ' << a.S; return out; }

struct Point {
    double x, y;
    
    Point() {}
    Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    
    Point operator+(const Point& src) {
        return Point(src.x + x, src.y + y);
    }
    
    Point operator-(const Point& src) {
        return Point(x - src.x, y - src.y);
    }
    
    Point operator*(double src) {
        return Point(x * src, y * src);
    }
    
    //* vector cross.
    double operator^(Point src) {
        return x * src.y - y * src.x;
    }
};

struct Line {
    Point sp, ep;
    
    Line() {}
    Line(Point sp, Point ep) : sp(sp), ep(ep) {}
    
    //* check if two segment intersect.
    bool is_intersect(Line src) {
        if (fcmp(ori(src.sp) * ori(src.ep)) < 0 and fcmp(src.ori(sp) * src.ori(ep)) < 0) {
            double t = ((src.ep - src.sp) ^ (sp - src.sp)) / ((ep - sp) ^ (src.ep - src.sp));
            
            return fcmp(t) >= 0 and fcmp(t, 1) <= 0;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    //* if two segment intersect, find the intersection point.
    Point intersect(Line src) {
        double t = ((src.ep - src.sp) ^ (sp - src.sp)) / ((ep - sp) ^ (src.ep - src.sp));
        
        return sp + (ep - sp) * t;
    }
    
    double ori(Point src) {
        return (ep - sp) ^ (src - sp);
    }
    
    bool operator<(Line src) const {
        if (fcmp(sp.y, src.sp.y) != 0)
            return sp.y < src.sp.y;
        return ep.y < src.ep.y;
    }
};

int next(int i, int n) {
    return (i + 1) % n;
}

int main()
{
    yccc;
    
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    
    //* the point list and the line list of polygons.
    vec<vec<Point>> p_list(n);
    vec<vec<Line>> l_list(n);
    
    //* x's set for all endpoints and intersection points
    vec<double> x_list;
    
    
    //* initializing point list and line list
    double total = 0, cover = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int m;
        cin >> m;
        
        p_list[i].resize(m);
        for (auto &k : p_list[i]) {
            cin >> k.x >> k.y;
            x_list.eb(k.x);
        }
        
        l_list[i].resize(m);
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
            l_list[i][k].sp = p_list[i][k];
            l_list[i][k].ep = p_list[i][next(k, m)];
        }
        
        //* calculate the polygon area.
        double tmp = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
            tmp += l_list[i][k].sp.x * l_list[i][k].ep.y - l_list[i][k].sp.y * l_list[i][k].ep.x;
        }
        
        total += abs(tmp);
    }
    
    //* find all intersection points
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int k = i+1; k < n; k++) {
            for (auto li : l_list[i])
                for (auto lk : l_list[k])
                    if (li.is_intersect(lk)) {
                        x_list.eb(li.intersect(lk).x);
                    }
        }
    
    sort(al(x_list));
    
    auto same = [](double a, double b) -> bool {
        return fcmp(a, b) == 0;
    };
    x_list.resize(unique(al(x_list), same) - x_list.begin());
    
    //* for each slicing, calculate the cover area.
    for (int i = 0; i < x_list.size() - 1; i++) {
        vec<pair<Line, int>> seg;
        
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for (auto line : l_list[k]) {
                
                //* check if line crosses this slicing
                if (fcmp(x_list[i], min(line.sp.x, line.ep.x)) >= 0 and fcmp(max(line.sp.x, line.ep.x), x_list[i+1]) >= 0) {
                    Point sub = line.ep - line.sp;
                    double t_sp = (x_list[i] - line.sp.x) / sub.x, t_ep = (x_list[i+1] - line.sp.x) / sub.x;
                    
                    seg.eb(Line(Point(x_list[i], line.sp.y + sub.y * t_sp), Point(x_list[i+1], line.sp.y + sub.y * t_ep)), k);
                }
            }
        }
        
        //* sort this slicing
        sort(al(seg));
        deq<bool> inside(n);
        
        int count = 0;
        Line prev;
        // cout << x_list[i] << ' ' << x_list[i+1] << endl;
        
        //* calculate cover area in this slicing.
        for (int k = 0; k < seg.size(); k++) {
            if (count)
                cover += ((seg[k].F.sp.y - prev.sp.y) + (seg[k].F.ep.y - prev.ep.y)) * (x_list[i+1] - x_list[i]);
            
            prev = seg[k].F;
            // cout << seg[k].S << ": (" << seg[k].F.sp.x << ", " << seg[k].F.sp.y << "), (" << seg[k].F.ep.x << ", " << seg[k].F.ep.y << ")" << endl;
            inside[k] = !inside[k];
            count += (inside[k] ? 1 : -1);
        }
    }
    
    //* answer
    cout << total / 2 << ' ' << cover / 2;
}
```

I can't not figure out which part I made a mistake :(

Comment: What is your question exactly? Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Please don't explain the problem with a document to download.